# Isometries on a real hilbert space, $H$, must be of the type $f(x) = Ux + a$ where $U^*U = I$ and $a \in H$

Tags: functional-analysis

> Isometries on a real hilbert space $H$ must be of the type $f(x) = Ux + a$ where $U^*U = I$, the identity operator, and $a \in H$.

I was thinking of using the fact that a map between Hilbert spaces which preserves the inner product must be a linear map. Then, letting $g(x) := f(x) - f(0)$, an isometry. Then I aimed to show that 
$$\langle g(x+y) , g(z) \rangle = \langle g(x) + g(y) , g(z) \rangle$$
so that I could conclude that $g(x+y) - g(x) - g(y)$ is in the intersection of the span of the image of $g$ and the orthogonal complement of the image of $g$, i.e.
$$g(x+y) - g(x) - g(y) \in [[\text{im}(g)]] \cap (\text{im}(g))^{\perp}.$$

However, I'm having difficulty actually getting this result, I could be going a very roundabout way of proving it. Is there a better (more logically clear) way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume $U$ is an isometry, meaning that $\|Ux-Uy\|=\|x-y\|$ for all $x,y$. Then $Vx=Ux-U0$ is an isometry that maps $0$ to $0$. It can be shown that $V$ is linear because of this, which gives $Ux = Vx+a$ where $a=U0$.

So assume that $V$ is an isometry that maps $0$ to $0$. Then $V(-x)=-V(x)$ must hold because
\begin{align}
        \|V(-x)+V(x)\|^2+\|V(-x)-V(x)\|^2 &=2\|V(-x)\|^2+2\|V(x)\|^2 \\
        \|V(-x)+V(x)\|^2+\|-x-x\|^2 & = 2\|x\|^2+2\|x\|^2 \\
          \|V(-x)+V(x)\|^2 & =0. \\
        \implies  V(-x) & = -V(x).
\end{align}
Therefore,
\begin{align}
         4(V(x),V(y)) &= \|V(x)+V(y)\|^2-\|V(x)-V(y)\|^2 \\
                      &= \|V(x)-V(-y)\|^2-\|x-y\|^2 \\
                      &= \|x-(-y)\|^2-\|x-y\|^2 \\
                      &= 4(x,y). \\
      \implies & (V(x),V(y)) =(x,y).
\end{align}
Now all properties of $V$ follow immediately. For example, if you expand
$\|V(\alpha x)-\alpha V(x)\|^2$ into a sum of terms $(Vx,Vx),(Vx,Vy),(Vy,Vy)$, these can then be replaced with $(x,x),(x,y),(y,y)$, respectively, leading to the equality
$$
             \|V(\alpha x)-\alpha V(x)\|^2=\|(\alpha x)-\alpha x\|^2=0 \\
        \implies V(\alpha x)=\alpha V(x).
$$
Similarly,
$$
         \|V(x+y)-V(x)-V(y)\|^2 = \|(x+y)-x-y\|^2 = 0 \\
      \implies V(x+y) = V(x)+V(y).
$$